# What can I expect to get in the Supply Chest?

Tags: boom-beach

After the recent app update, one of the new additions to the game is the Supply Chest. It unlocks after 5 Victory Points. I'm at level 40. What can I expect to get in the Supply Chest? Is it more or less equivalent to the daily reward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They offer any three of the following rewards: Gold, Wood, Stone, Iron, Diamonds, and Power Stones.

In addition to this, they will also contain Intel.

These rewards vary based on your rank, so earn a high rank in order to receive better rewards. See [this table](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Supply_Chest#Trivia) to know how much you'll get from Supply Chest